# helix-3d-toolkit Object group names

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

i'm using helix-3d-toolkit to show 3ds models by using FileModelVisual3D.
If i open the 3ds file in 3d max so i can see the group names in the object explorer. 
Is there any way to get the group names from a model.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to StudioReader class in order to assign the group name to the DependencyProperty Name of GeometryModel3D